# how to retrieve string or integer value from one class to another class

Tags: iphone

i am creating two classes named classA and classB.

i need to get string or integer value from classA to classB.

I know one way that is using NSUserdefaults.

But i have multiple values.

i am trying using this also.

```
classB *obj = [[classB alloc]init];
NSLog(@"string value is %@",obj.string);
```

but it always returns null and application quits.

can any one please help me.

how can i retrieve  string or integer values from one class to another class.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: Can u tel, how u initializing the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose make NSString and NSInteger as a property then synthesize it for setter and getter.

Now for accsing this you need the object of thet class and you can simply access as you are doing.

OR make properties in AppDelegate class and synthesize it. and by making object of AppDelegate class you can access thes properties.

For making appObject

```
YourAppDelegateClass *obj=(YourAppDelegateClass *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you allocate and init a Object,its memory will be newly allocated and initialized.

So previously initialized value will be became null.To obtain the previous value,You need to access the obj through which you have initialized the string.

You can try setter and getter method of the two different class to set and get the value.

Comment: Through normal method declarations.Can you tel me wat value u have in the class B.How is ur class code looks like?

Comment: Or u can take the values through Application Delegate as mentioned by kingofBliss..

Answer (score 0):

You should follow singleton concept to do so.

Or else use appDelegate to transfer value of between different class.